# Expressing "Every even number is the difference of two primes" in symbols

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

Consider this conjecture:

*"Every even number is the difference of two primes."*

Express this statement in terms of quantifiers, variables, equality/inequality symbols, logical operators, and the following two predicates.

- $P(n)$: "$n$ is a prime number."
- $E(n)$: "$n$ is an even number."

My answer: $$∀x∃y,z>0( E(x) → (P(y)∧P(z)∧(y < z)∧(y ∧ x = z))).$$
I want it to say: "For every value of $x$, there exists at least two positive integers $y$ and $z$, such that if $x$ is an even number, that implies $y$, $z$ are prime numbers AND $y$ is smaller than $z$ AND $x + y$ is equivalent to $z$."

I am pretty sure I am wrong, especially with the part $(y ∧ x = z)$ because I do not know how to express the idea of "subtraction" or "difference" with the symbols available to me.

What am I missing?

Comment: "$n$ is smaller than $m$" is $\exists k (m=n+k)$.

Comment: If you have no "smaller than" you do not have $x > 0$ also ...

Comment: Assume as universe the collection of positive integers : $1,2,\ldots$. In this way, you have $∀x∃y∃z \ldots$

Comment: "x + y is equal [not : equivalent] to z" must be $x+y=z$. And this is enough: if x=z-y, then $z=x+y$.

Comment: Is addition assumed or do you have to come up with your own definition for it? In the first case, you can express subtraction as addition ($a - b = c \rightarrow b + c = a$). In the second case, you need at least the zero number and a successor function to define addition and then you can proceed as in the first case.

Comment: The issue is that you are lacking also of *addition* symbol... Thus, how to express "difference" withou : subtraction, addition, etc. ?

Comment: @frabala The question doesn't outright prohibit me from using addition operator. Are you saying that my only choices are either 1) assume I can use addition, or 2) create a new function that acts like an addition operator?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That's a good question. Lets assume I can in fact use the addition operator. Would this new answer be satisfactory? ∀x∃y∃z>0(E(x)→(P(y)∧P(z)∧(y<z)∧(y+x=z))).

Comment: @potatoguy the exists of $x,y$ is as a result of $E(x)$ so it would be better to say: ∀x(E(x)→(∃y∃z(P(y)∧P(z)∧(y<z)∧(y+x=z))))

Answer (score 1):

Provided the addition operator, here's a conversion from natural language to a logical formula. I've put it step by step:

1. "Every even number is the difference between two primes".
2. "Every number, if it is even then it is the difference of two primes".
3. $\forall x$, "if $x$ is even, then it is the difference of two primes".
4. $\forall x, E(x) \rightarrow$ "$x$ is the difference of two primes".
5. $\forall x, E(x) \rightarrow$ "there are two prime numbers $y$ and $z$ such that $y - z = x$".
6. $\forall x, E(x) \rightarrow$ "there are two prime numbers $y$ and $z$ such that $y = x + z$".
7. $\forall x, E(x) \rightarrow$ "there are two numbers $y$ and $z$ such that they are prime and $y = x + z$".
8. $\forall x, E(x) \rightarrow \exists~y~z$, "such that they are prime and $y = x + z$".
9. $\forall x, E(x) \rightarrow \exists~y~z, P(y) \land P(z) $and $y = x + z$".
10. $\forall x, E(x) \rightarrow \exists~y~z, P(y) \land P(z) \land y = x + z$.